# not able to run protractor typescript samples getting below error installed types jasmine etc

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm not able to run protractor typescript samples. I'm getting error bellow. I've installed types jasmine etc.

This is my code:

```
import {Config} from 'protractor';
export let config: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    specs: [ 'spec.js' ],
    seleniumAddress: 'localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    // You could set no globals to true to avoid jQuery '$' and protractor '$'
    // collisions on the global namespace.
    noGlobals: true
};
```

I get this error:

> ```
> root@localhost exampleTypescript]# protractor conf.ts
>   [06:08:07] E/configParser - Error code: 105
>   [06:08:07] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.ts
>   [06:08:07] E/configParser - /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/exampleTypescript/conf.ts:11
>   import {Config} from 'protractor';
>   ^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `protractor.conf.js` instead of `protractor.conf.ts`. In your `tsconfig.js` you set up a folder for compiled files (from `ts` to `js`) = `outDir` property. So, you will need to run the `protractor.conf.js` from the folder that you setup in `tsconfig`, for example `node ./dist/config/protractor.conf.js` instead of `node ./config/protractor.conf.js`